# Is the equation below means in a MIP model

Tags: gams-math

As the title mentioned

`sum((r,l), Mer.l(e,r) * Mel(e,l)) =e= 0;`

I use a GAMS mip model to solve a problem, and Mer(e,r) and Mel(e,l) are both binary variables, and if I did not write the `.l` suffix, the compile will give `Endogenous relational operations require model type "dnlp""` error message, but I am not sure the equation above staying the original meaning that is the Mer(e,r) still a variable? and is it still changeable with the mip solving process?

Comment: You should almost never use .l in an equation. Either the variable is endogenous or it should be fixed before solving. 
Can you show a minimal working example to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Mer.l, the model will not use Mer as a variable that gets optimized anymore, but will use the (initial) levels of the variables Mer as constant numbers. But you could reformualte your equation, so that it stays linear. As I understand it, you want to make sure that for each e and each combination of r and l you will never get Mer=1 and Mel=1 (one could be 1 or both should be 0). So you could formulate is as e.g.:

```
equation e(e,r,l);
e(e,r,l).. Mer(e,r) + Mel(e,l) =l= 1;
```

I hope that helps,
Lutz

Comment: it works, but this increase the the number of equations rapidly with the increasing of r and l, will it influence the solving time of the model?

Comment: Yes, that could happen. But even if it runs a little longer, it does at least what you want.

Comment: yeah, but I have some more equations are nonlinear, and they seem no so easy to to reformulated. is there any other model that allowing part of linear equations and others are not?